# Как сделать горизонтально-вертикальную форму в Bootstrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap4

Пытаюсь сделать форму в виде: [image]

Пытаюсь написать так:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="question" class="sr-only">Question</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="question" rows="4" placeholder="text" ></textarea>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="email" class="sr-only">E-mail</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="E-mail">
     </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Но форма выглядит почему-то так:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

В вашем примере неправильно отформатирован код, если отформатировать увидите ошибку (все элементы формы находятся в одном `col-md-6`).

Более правильно вынести их в разные колонки, пример:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="question" class="sr-only">Question</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="question" rows="4" placeholder="text"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="email" class="sr-only">E-mail</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="E-mail">
      <br>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```